# how to send the message to TOPIC then to MDB?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ibm-mq, websphere-7

In our project we are making use of Websphere MQ.

Initially we are sending the message to Queue using RFHUtil.

it is required that we have to make use of Topic.

so how we have to send message to topic..??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are number of samples shipped with WebSphere MQ v7.x. One such sample is `amqspub` that can be used to send publications to a topic. Here is how you use this sample application

```
amqspub "/SPORTS/FOOTBALL/BARCA" QMSPORT
```

where "/SPORTS/FOOTBALL/BARCA" is the topic string and QMSPORT is queue manager name. There are number Java samples also.